# Ghostscript PS to PDF problem with some characters

Tags: java, pdf, ghostscript, postscript, file-conversion

I'm using the ghost4j jar to convert PostScript to PDF.  The conversion is failing when certain upper-ASCII characters are present in the content.  Oddly, not all upper-ASCII cause the problem.  The error information coming out of Ghostscript is not that helpful to me.

Sample code that produces the problem is:

```
private void convertPSToPDF()
{
    try
    {
        File ps = new File( "c:\\temp\\gsinput.ps" );

        PSDocument document = new PSDocument();
        document.load( ps );

        File pdf = new File( "c:\\temp\\gsoutput.pdf" );

        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream( pdf );

        try
        {
            PDFConverter converter = new PDFConverter();
            converter.setPDFSettings( PDFConverter.OPTION_PDFSETTINGS_PRINTER );

            converter.convert( document, stream );
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.close();
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

The log4j output is the following:

```
0 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.ghost4j.Ghostscript  - Error: /undefined in y0m
1 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.ghost4j.Ghostscript  - Operand stack:
1 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.ghost4j.Ghostscript  -    (3)   375.4   36.3
1 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.ghost4j.Ghostscript  - Execution stack:
2 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.ghost4j.Ghostscript  -    %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2045   1   3   %oparray_pop   2044   1   3   %oparray_pop   2025   1   3   %oparray_pop   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
2 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.ghost4j.Ghostscript  - Dictionary stack:
2 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.ghost4j.Ghostscript  -    --dict:961/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:282/300(L)--
2 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.ghost4j.Ghostscript  - Current allocation mode is local
2 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.ghost4j.Ghostscript  - Last OS error: No such file or directory
2 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR org.ghost4j.Ghostscript  - GPL Ghostscript 9.26: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

This seemed to implicate the line of PostScript:

```
(3)375.4 36.3 y0 bnum
```

However, I can't see anything wrong with that and that line executes fine if I make a small change elsewhere in the file.  I noticed that the problem only occurred on source files that had either the 'í' or the 'á' character in them...but the 'ú' seemed fine.

Based on that, the piece of PostScript that appears to produce the problem is just trying to write some string literals:

```
328.9 -25.8 M /str{ 18.0 F4 [(An S)/uacute(is)/iacute(n Ban)]arrayshow}def
strw w 0.5 mul neg 0 RM str
0.0 -36.8 M  10.0 F4 (Other)show
0 -36.80 T
0 -6.00 T
```

If I change the PostScript to replace the 'í' character (/iacute) with a normal 'i', the problem disappears.  This code will work:

```
328.9 -25.8 M /str{ 18.0 F4 [(An S)/uacute(isin Ban)]arrayshow}def
strw w 0.5 mul neg 0 RM str
0.0 -36.8 M  10.0 F4 (Other)show
0 -36.80 T
0 -6.00 T
```

Following the log4j output, I get an IOException.  It seems somewhat like this is just poor error handling inside the code since we shouldn't be deleting a file at this point.  The top of the call stack is:

```
java.io.IOException: Temporary file C:\Users\Tad\AppData\Local\Temp\ghost4j\452f1844-372a-4300-b570-86ec650fe4b6@17580 cannot be deleted
    at org.ghost4j.util.DiskStore.removeFile(DiskStore.java:133)
```

No special fonts; just Times Roman.  I'm using v9.26 of the Ghostscript DLL.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might get around this?  I really do not want to replace those foreign characters in the final output if there's any way to avoid it.

Comment: does the same error happen when you try the conversion on a commandline with `ps2pdf gsinput.ps`?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  I suppose I could rewrite the code to have the conversion done externally.  I'm assuming that this is a configuration issue since the underlying code is clearly capable of performing the conversion.  Unfortunately, I can't find documentation to show what configuration.

Comment: Well you aren't using Ghostscript directly, so this isn't really a Ghostscript question per se, and it makes it hard for me to comment. If you could replicate the problem using a Ghostscript command line that would help. I'd also need to see the source PostScript program, there isn't enough context here to see what's really happening.

Comment: I've tried a few times to replicate it from the command line; I have no luck so far but I'll keep trying.  The PostScript is 804 lines long.  Is there some way to attach a file here?